# Looping through cells, building a range in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, range

I am looking to loop through cells and build a range for a graph. My main issue is that I cannot figure out how to incorporate the 'i' into the range. Example:

```
Dim name As String
Dim newChart as Chart
Dim i as Integer
Set newChart = Charts.add    

For i = 1 To 20

    accName = Range("C" & i).Value          'I understand why this works. 

    With newChart
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries     
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = accName
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = wb.Worksheets("Summary-Account").Range("E&i:G&i, I&i:K&i, M&i:O&i, Q&i:S&i")          'How can I get this to work?
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = wb.Worksheets("Summary-Account").Range("E3:G3, I3:K3, M3:O3, Q3:S3")
    End With

    i = i + 1

Loop
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are creating a single chart `newChart = Charts.Add` and then creating 20 different names (`accName`) in the loop. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AlexP I think that he wants to create 20 different curves on the chart.

Comment: Oh, and also, `SeriesCollection()` starts at "0", like every array in VB.

Comment: Do you know how to use `.Resize()` or `.Offset()` in ranges to target cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to have:

```
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = wb.Worksheets("Summary-Account").Range("E" & i & ":G" & i & ", I" & i & ":K" & i & ", M" & i & ":O" & i & ", Q" & i & ":S" & i)
```

Not the clearest line ever, but should give you the pattern to go by.  There are other problems like needing a "Next i" instead of a "Loop" and no i=i+1, but on my computer this gave me a graph with multiple series on it.

Answer (score 3):

1. You **don't** increment manually `i`.
   The function `for loop` already does it for you.
   So **remove** that `i = i + 1`.
2. Now, to make your `Range` work, you would need its "" to be something like this : `Range("E" & i & ":G" & i`). I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve with trying to take data from 6 different columns.. See [range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238(v=office.15).aspx) for further information.

Comment: What if i wanted to increment i by 6 every time? What is the syntax for that?

Comment: @Guiltyberto That would be `For i = 1 To 20 Step 6`

Answer (score 0):

use `Next i` instead of `Loop`; and get rid of that `i = i+1`.
Also, use `"E" & i & ":G" & i`  instead of `"E&i:G&i"`

One step further, in vba

```
Dim i as double
For i = 1 to 100 Step 10  '<= Step 10 means when updating i, i = i + 10, and default value would be 1
Loop  '<=breaks here, compile error is expected.
```

this is not even valid in syntax, the keyword `Loop` is associated with another keyword `Do`, and `For` is associated with `Next`

Comment: o, didnt check out the far right hand side.. anyways, in terms of ur problem, if u go "E&i:G&i, I&i:K&i, M&i:O&i, Q&i:S&i", vba wouldnt recognize the number i. what it reads is something like Ei:Gi, which is not valid in terms of the syntax and not what u attempt to do(E1:G1 is what u looking for). it would consider it as string i. with that being said, if u wanna use numbers and updating it, u should have done something like "E" & i & ":G" & i

Comment: What if I wanted: 

`Dim i as Integer

Do While Range("C" & i).Value <> ""
'stuff here
i = i + 6
Loop`

Comment: But i need a `Do While`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range("E1").Resize(20,1).Value
```

this will copy all the values into an array for use in series collection